# TypeError:Object(...) is not a function in export Default

Tags: reactjs, redux, higher-order-components

My higher order component with error handler was working fine , now i don't know what happened It's not working and showing a TypeError.
Below I have posted picture and code for the following.
I tried Rewriting the entire file but it still didn't work.
I checked the original source code and it's the same as below.
There is a file which uses this same higher order component and it does not show any error . please help

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Order from '../../Components/Order/Order';
import axios from '../../axios-order';

import * as actions from '../../store/actions/index';
import Spinner from '../../Components/UI/Spinner/Spinner';
import WithErrorHandler from '../../hoc/withErrorHandler/withErrorHandler'

class Orders extends Component {
    componentDidMount () {
        this.props.onFetchOrders(this.props.token, this.props.userId);
    }

    render () {
        let orders = <Spinner />;
        if ( !this.props.loading ) {
            orders = this.props.orders.map( order => (
                <Order
                    key={order.id}
                    ingredients={order.ingredients}
                    price={order.price} />
            ) )
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {orders}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        orders: state.order.orders,
        loading: state.order.loading,
        token: state.auth.token,
        userId: state.auth.userId
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onFetchOrders: (token, userId) => dispatch( actions.fetchOrders(token, userId) )
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(WithErrorHandler(Orders,axios));
```

WithErrorHandler.js File:

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import Modal from '../../Components/UI/Modal/Modal'
import Auxillary from '../Auxillary'
import Orders from '../../Containers/Orders/Orders';



const withErrorHandler = ( WrappedComponent, axios ) => {
    return class extends Component {
        state = {
            error: null
        }

        componentWillMount () {
            this.reqInterceptor = axios.interceptors.request.use( req => {
                this.setState( { error: null } );
                return req;
            } );
            this.resInterceptor = axios.interceptors.response.use( res => res, error => {
                this.setState( { error: error } );
            } );
        }

        componentWillUnmount () {
            axios.interceptors.request.eject( this.reqInterceptor );
            axios.interceptors.response.eject( this.resInterceptor );
        }

        errorConfirmedHandler = () => {
            this.setState( { error: null } );
        }

        render () {
            return (
                <Auxillary>
                    <Modal
                        show={this.state.error}
                        modalClosed={this.errorConfirmedHandler}>
                        {this.state.error ? this.state.error.message : null}
                    </Modal>
                    <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />
                </Auxillary>
            );
        }
    }
}

export default withErrorHandler;
```

The error is showing up in the file Orders.js and I cant seem to locate it

[image: The Error]

Comment: It looks like `withErrorHandler` is a proper function, are you sure the code you have in your question is causing that error? ;) can you check again? Maybe you can try reproducing on `codesandbox`

Comment: Yeah I am also aware of that and that's what troubling me , maybe the problem is not withErrorahandler.js but order.js

Comment: Yeahhh maaaybe your `actions.fetchOrders(token, userId)` is not declared correctly? Can you check `fetchOrders` is a function and not an object?

Comment: Cant seem to find an error